# Why didn't he give Sam the antidote?

Tags: i-am-legend

In [*I Am Legend* (2007)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0480249/), Robert and Sam get ambushed and Sam ends up getting bitten by the zombie dogs. Since dogs are only immune to the airborne version, Sam got infected. Robert takes Sam back to his lab where he ends up killing her after she turns.

Why not give Sam the antidote? He saw clearly that the rat had shown signs of regression or that the virus was no longer dominant. There wasn't any reason (that I could see at least) to not give Sam the antidote. The human subject was still alive at that point as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

He did give Sam the antidote, it just doesn't appear to have worked. The clip below has him putting out a syringe and injecting Sam, but her turning and becoming agressive anyways (hence Robert strangling her, so that she doesn't become a vampire).

Presumably she was too far gone into the infection, or the compound wasn't that effective, or something; but he did try.

Comment: I'll have to rewatch it, I did not see that part at all...

Comment: As an added to this i believe that the antidote was not perfected at this point either. It was only after he was rescued by the other 2 after trying to kill himself and was in his lab that he realised the antidote worked on the human test subject.

Comment: Shouldn't "vampire" read "zombie" above? It's basically a zombie movie.

Comment: @FaheemMitha the book is about vampires (although very different to the ones in the film, sadly for the film) and in the film the monsters are fast and allergic to sunlight. Sounds like vampires anyway, although their attributes make them a weird vampire-zombie hybrid.